# How to revert to default width in explorer panel?

Tags: visual-studio-code

There's a left panel, called Explorer in VSCode:

[image]

I resized it accidentally, but is there a way to reset it to default width? As when you just install vscode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hover over the edge of the explorer so that the `<->` cursor appears for resizing, then double click. I can confirm that this works on Windows at least.

Comment: Nice, it works on OSX either :) How did you found it?

Comment: I used to do it all the time in visual studio so when I saw your question I just checked to see if it worked in vscode

Comment: For me on version 1.61.2, double-clicking the right border resizes to accommodate the longest file name if you're in the file explored pane.